# How to know that my ubuntu upgrade process worked out perfectly!

Tags: server, upgrade, 14.04

I wanted to upgrade my Ubuntu 13.10 VPS to 14.04, but during the upgrade process I faced an issue in my command line and it seemed to me that the upgrade process didn't terminate normally.

And I restart the session, when I run command `sudo apt-get update`
it resumed the upgrade process again from where it stopped earlier. Everything is [ok] I think. But to be sure, I wanted to know that the upgrade process went perfectly. Nothing is missing in the server.

- How can I do that?

Comment: `sudo apt-get -f install` what does it tell you?

Comment: sudo dpkg --configure -a   Should also be run

Comment: @CharlesGreen Yea, when I run your command, it shows mysql server errors. And it also saying that dependency problem. Nothing else. So I can assume there is only one thing left from my upgrade process which MySQL server? everything else is okay? thanks for the help mate.

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish when I run you command I can see the following. It seems something wrong with MySQL: 
'code'
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
'code'

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish I didn't restarted the system after upgrade, that's why the MySQL issue was showing I think. Now when I reboot the system and run this command: 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' . MySQL gets installed perfectly and when I have run your command, it shows as follows:
'Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-iostreams1.53.0 libclass-isa-perl libswitch-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.'

Comment: @Md. Khairul Hasan Sujan - then we ca assume that everything is working well now?  I'd ask you to post an answer to your own question so that this question becomes closed in the ask archives.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I have answered the question. :) This is my first contribution to ask ubuntu. Love you all by the way.

Comment: Good job - the final component is to check your own answer as accepted - I think the 'ask' community gives you points for doing this!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to answer the question I posted earlier as the issue is fixed now. As the upgrade process didn't terminate normally, I had to resume the upgrade process writing this command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then I could understand that only MySQL Server upgrade remaining from the whole ubuntu 14.04 upgrade. But it was showing an error in upgrading MySQL. The issue was showing because I didn't reboot my system. So I need to reboot it first before MySQL issue gets fixed:

```
sudo reboot
```

As the SSH connection terminated as I have rebooted the system. I had to reconnect it. And then when I run the following command again, MySQL got updated properly:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And then I run the following command to see it everything is okay in my upgrade process:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

It turned out with this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
   libboost-iostreams1.53.0 libclass-isa-perl libswitch-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Now I am sure that my system is perfectly upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 TrustyTahr. Bam!

Comment: Also run `sudo apt-get autoremove` as it tells you to clean unneeded packages.